# Sentry Configuration not Working in Consumer Base Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

recently our 12+ Micro service Running in AWS Server with Different Port.
some project are api base and some Project are consumer base so recently i was configured sentry in All this Project ans we use same DNS with Different EVN like`

this API Project

1. PROJECT:API

configuration like

```
sentry.dns=exmpale1
application.enviroment=PROD_API
```

this are Consumer base Project

2. PROJECT:BACK
   configuration like

```
sentry.dns=exmpale1
application.enviroment=PROD_BACK
```

3. PROJECT:OUT

configuration like

```
sentry.dns=exmpale1
application.enviroment=PROD_OUT
```

4. PROJECT:IN

configuration like

```
sentry.dns=exmpale1
application.enviroment=PROD_IN
```

Same Configuration Java Class for All Project it Like

```java
@Configuration
public class SentryConfiguration {

  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SentryConfiguration.class);
  
  @Value("${sentry.dsn:null}")
  private String dsn;

  @Value("${application.environment:local}")
  private String environment;

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    if (!"null".equalsIgnoreCase(dsn)) {
      SentryClient sentryClient = Sentry.init(dsn);
      sentryClient.setEnvironment(environment);
      logger.info("Sentry Configured for BACK");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using Sentry Java SDK 1.x. Please upgrade to the latest (currently 5.1.0), and use the `sentry-spring-boot-starter` with which you can configure environment in `application.properties` file without any extra Java code:

```
sentry.dns=exmpale1
sentry.enviroment=PROD_IN
```

More on how to use Sentry Spring Boot Starter: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/